# Web Scraping with Python - Looping for city name, clicking and get interested value

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my first time with Python and web scraping. Have been looking around and still unable to get what I need to do.

Below are print screen of the elements that I've used via Chrome.

As you can see, it is from the dropdown 'Apartments'.

My 1st step in trying to do is get the list of cities from the drop down

My 2nd step is then, from the given city list, go to each of them (...url.../Brantford/   for example)

My 3rd step is then, given the available apartments, click each of the available apartments to get the price range for each bedroom type

Currently, I am JUST trying to 'loop' through the cities in the first step and it's not working.

Could you please help me out as well, if there's a good forum, article, tutorial etc that's good for beginner like me to read and learn. I'd really like to be good in this so that I may give me to society one day.

Thank you!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments-for-rent/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

dropdown_list = soup.find(".child-pages dropdown-menu a href")

print (dropdown_list.prettify())
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7JLP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the elements by the class and a child "a" node. Then access the attribute "href" and add a domain name.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.homestead.ca/apartments-for-rent/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

dropdown_list = soup.select(".primary .child-pages a")
links=['http://www.homestead.ca'+x['href'] for x in dropdown_list]
print (links)

city_names=[x.text for x in dropdown_list]
print (city_names)

result=[]

for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    ...
    result.append(...)
```

Explanation:

```
soup.select(".primary .child-pages a")
```

Using CSS selector I select the "a" nodes that are children of a node with the class "child-pages" which is a child of the the node with a class "primary". There were two nodes with class "child-pages" and I filtered one that was under node with "primary" class.

```
[x.text for x in dropdown_list]
```

This is a list comprehension in Python. It means that I choose all elements of dropdown_list and then take only the attribute text of each of them and then return as a list.

You can then iterate over the links and append the data to a list (here "result").

I found this introduction to BeautifulSoup pretty good though without going through the links: http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/intro-to-beautiful-soup

I would also recommend reading a book. For example this one: [Web Scraping with Python: Collecting Data from the Modern Web](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491910291)

Comment: Thanks Keiv.fly for your response. Like I said, I'm totally new in Python, and basically been googling and finding answers and trying to implement it.

I don't know anything about XPath...where can I learn it?

Also, can you explain why is it '.child-pages a'? The element thing is really that confuses me, and with the addition of how python 'language' makes these 2 as ancient language.

Comment: Instead of getting the href link, is it possible to ONLY just get the city name?

Currently, the 'answer' is by the URL...and it appears twice.

Comment: I edited the answer to get the city names working on the doubling of URLs

Comment: So you mean you purposefully have it double? Meaning that the city appears twice?

Comment: I edited the code. Now the cities are not doubled. I meant I was looking for the way to change the code.

Comment: Thanks Keiv.fly.

I've vote for the 'Answer is useful' and 'Accept this answer'

Honestly speaking, I have no idea of what you did. Would you be kind enough to explain what it does?

Also, now that I have the city name and the href as well, how do I go about doing the 2nd step, which is taking each individual apartment, clicking it and get the value of interest? Any forum, article, video tutorial that I can watch and learn?